# Which Azure Storage / Database Technology to make use of for large scale logging

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, azure-sql-database, document-oriented

I am looking into making use of Azure hosting services in order to develop a logging service for our company.

Azure has a number of storage options available (I have listed links below). However I am not sure which one would be best suited for my needs. I am coming from a MS SQL Server background so I am probably not as open minded as I should be, hence my question here is to try and explore other more suitable options.  If any one knows of any place where I can get design help specifically for azure please let me know, as I have not been able to find any.

Requirements:

Background: We are looking to log messages from a variety of types of devices which the company owns. This needs to be on a mass scale. Several million entries per day. As much as I have tried to keep the design a fixed structure, due to the variety of device types out their they messages differ completely and have different elements. I would somehow like to still be able to query message specific attributes. (How one would do this, I do not know).

- All messages come into this logging service as A JSON object. The JSON object obviously varies based on the type of device which sent the message and the type of message the device is sending.
- There will be some common attributes such as deviceID, LogTime,customerId etc.
- Due to the mention of above, it seems that a document / object store technology would suit the application better. However as mentioned above I have not have much exposure to these types of technologies. Will it be able to efficiently handle the load, and queries etc.
- We will need to be able to store months of log values without slowing down daily queries to a halt.
- Data analytic's and big queries should be able to be done on the data after some time of running. I'm not sure if one would make use of a different mechanism for this? Possibly a sort of storage layer and then a big data layer. However my storage mechanism needs to keep this future features in mind.

Azure offers the following storage and database services:

1. [Sql Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/sql-database/)
2. [DocumentDb](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/documentdb/)
3. [Storage: Blobs, Tables,Queues,Files and Disks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/storage/)
4. [StorSimple Hybrid cloud Stroage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/storsimple/)
5. [SQL Data Warehouse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/sql-data-warehouse/)

I am sorry, I know this question is quite general and possibly open ended. I am not looking for anyone to just give the the complete solution in my hand. I am looking for some guidance in the right direction and experience from people who have already gone down this road before.